# Searchview searches only whole words instead searching in content

Tags: android, arraylist, textwatcher, android-search

I have a searchfield who searches in my Arrayadapter

```
   inputSearch.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence cs, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {
            ZT.this.adapter.getFilter().filter(cs);  
        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2,
                int arg3) {


        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {

        }
    });
```

It only searches the whole word. For example:

```
Baloon
```

Seach `Bal` returns `Baloon`, Searching `oon` returns nothing. And I would like that he'll return `Baloon` in this case.

Thanks for helping.

Comment: its becuase it search based on starting characters. not any other place.

Comment: how can I change this, add a custom filter?

Answer (score 0):

you can use FilterQueryProvider and pass it into adapter.setFilterQueryProvider().

```
adapter.setFilterQueryProvider(new FilterQueryProvider() {
    public Cursor runQuery(CharSequence constraint) {
        String s = '%' + constraint.toString() + '%';
        return getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, 
            new String[] {Phone._ID, Phone.DISPLAY_NAME, Phone.NUMBER},
            Phone.DISPLAY_NAME + ' LIKE ? OR ' + Phone.NUMBER + ' LIKE ?',
            new String[] { s, s },
            null);
    }
});
```

use this with adapter.